# This question is related to present perfect tense and the uses of never in it

Tags: present-tense

> They have never returned from that city.

This is a single time event, so can we use "never" in this sentence?

Instead of this can we use this?:

> They have not returned from that city.

Comment: Of course, why not? The use of never is not tense related.

Answer (score 1):

> They have never returned from that city.

vs

> They have not returned from that city.

In this specific case, there's not much difference between the 2. They're both acceptable and mean the same thing. "Never" can be used with "single time" events too. However, there is some slight difference between `never` and `not`.

In your example, using `have not returned` implies *they* haven't returned **yet**. This means they haven't returned yet, but are expected to return in the future.

When you use `have never returned`, it can mean the exact same as using `not`, but it can also be interpreted as "They have not returned and they (likely) **will not** return." In this case, we do **not** expect *them* to return.

Basically, using `not` implies that you expect the `[action/verb]` to happen later in the future and using `never` implies you expected them to `[verb]` in the past, but now you no longer expect that. Here's a "fun" example:

---

Jimmy's diary:

Day 1:

Dad left to go to war. He said he'd be back in a year

[1 year later]

Dad has **not** returned. He's late...

[2 years later]

Dad has **never** returned. Mom said he won't be coming back...

---

As you can see, the difference is mainly whether or not you expect the `[action/verb]` to happen in the future.

Comment: Never often negates an *expectation*.  *I did not meet John in Rome [along with 7.2 billion other people],*  vs  *I never met John in Rome [but I had planned on it.]*

Answer (score 0):

"Every year our most intelligent young people go to Paris. They have never returned from that city".

That is a continuing event.

"Jack and Jill went to Paris last week. They have not returned from that city".

That is a one time event.